# Use Charles Proxy to monitor tomcat service

Tags: java, tomcat, charles-proxy

I'm using Charles Proxy to monitor the traffic in a tomcat service, after reading the document I add a line in catalina.bat:

set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -agentpath:C:\yjpagent.dll -Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8888 -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8888

But the Charles Proxy does not show anything when the service runs.

Any idea what should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are using REST request such as HttpClient in tomcat service?

Answer (score 0):

**Change this:**

```
-Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
```

**To:**

```
-Dhttps.proxyHost=localhost.charlesproxy.com  -Dhttp.proxyHost=localhost.charlesproxy.com
```

**Documentation:** [here](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/localhost-traffic-doesnt-appear-in-charles/)

If this doesn't work for you. Add the content below to the file `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1  localhost.charlesproxy.com
```